# Grammar-The future tense

Tags: grammar

I am learning future tense now. However, I don't what is the difference between "will-"and "be going to-".

Comment: See ELL, it's there.

Answer (score -1):

Use "will" when you talk of spontaneous actions.
Use "to be going to" to describe schedules or plans
compare:
I need to go now. - Wait, I will see you off.
We are leaving for Paris tomorrow. We are going to visit all the sights there!